# Understanding the difference between a recursive capture in a grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I'm trying to understand the difference between the following two very basic grammars to capture a dotted path (such as a json path):

```
grammar Id;
root: pathExpr EOF;

pathExpr
    : pathExpr '.' Identifier // Difference is here
    | pathExpr '[' Index ']'
    | Identifier
  ;

Identifier: [a-zA-Z]+;
Index: [0-9]+;

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

And:

```
grammar Id;
root: pathExpr EOF;

pathExpr
    : pathExpr '.' pathExpr // Difference is here
    | pathExpr '[' Index ']'
    | Identifier
  ;

Identifier: [a-zA-Z]+;
Index: [0-9]+;

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Would the recursive call in the dotted-path be correctly supplied as `pathExpr '.' pathExpr` or `pathExpr '.' Identifier`. What is the difference between the two and why would one be used over the other?

Comment: The second one is ambiguous; the first is not. Does it matter? Depends on your parser generator. But FWIW, I'd always go for the unambiguous grammar.

Comment: @rici -- I see. Can you explain a bit why the second one is ambiguous? That's the part I don't really get.

Comment: `a.b.c` is two pathExpr, but where do they begin and end?

Comment: In Antlr4, there isn't a difference. The [classic textbook example Arith grammar is ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar#Addition_and_subtraction) (`grammar Arith; file_ : e EOF; e : e ('+' | '-') e | N ; N : [0-9]+ ; WS : [ \r\n\t] + -> skip;`), but Antlr4 doesn't report any ambiguity, and there is no performance hit. On the other hand, `grammar Arith2; file_ : e EOF; e : e ('+' | '-') e | e ('+' | '-') N | N ; N : [0-9]+ ; WS : [ \r\n\t] + -> skip;` has an ambiguity that can cause performance problems. Antlr can't make filet mignon out of spam. Use the tools to help.